# Map numbers to name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, mapping

I have no Idea, how to map an array or hash in rails.
In the Layout I want to map some numbers.

How do I map that number? I think I should put the array in the model and reference with a class. Model.get_name('number')
But I have no Idea how to write that class. I googled a lot, but nothing was similar to my problem.

```
names = {210 => "Alex", 211 => "Brian", 212 => "Max", 221 => "Claire",230 => "Anna"}

get_name(id)
   names.each {|id,v| (v)}
   puts v
end
```

I think the solution have to be something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `map`, define the constant with hash which contain key-value pair of ids and names, you can just get `value` from the hash by `key`:

```
class M
  Names = {210 => "Alex", 
           211 => "Brian", 
           212 => "Max", 
           221 => "Claire",
           230 => "Anna"}
end
```

and use it like:

```
M::Names[211] => "Brian"
```

[Read more about hashes in **Ruby**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm)

Comment: That constant works. If I write <%= M::Names[210] %> but when I try <%= M::Names[object.number] %> I don't get the output.

Comment: @RickySpanish that is in the `object.number` variable?

Comment: Yes. The number is in object.number.

Comment: is the type of `object.number` is an integer or string? `<%= object.number.class %>`

Comment: Oh gosh, thank you for the hint... ```.to_i``` works.